# Не выпадает подменю

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

Не выпадает подменю `Bootstrap 3`

[image: Скриншот]

**Мой код:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="ru">

<head>


  <script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="bootstrap@3.3.5" data-semver="3.3.5" src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.5" data-semver="1.5.5" src="app"></script>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

  <div class="navbar navbar-default navigation-mobile col-md-12" role="navigation">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Отдельная ссылка</a></li>
            <li class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Еще одна отдельная ссылка</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Сделайте рабочий пример, где можно будет увидеть проблему. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @E_K, готово. Пример иллюстрирует именно то, что и у меня. У меня до этого была проблемы с выпаданием всего меню, т.е. оно вообще не выпадало. Решил проблему подключением JS. После этого меню выпадало, а подменю не реагирует. Я вообще не понимаю, в официальной документации есть только 3 строки подключения с CDN, которые не дали мне возможности использования меню вида `гамбургер`

Comment: С Bootstrap 4 все работает.

Comment: Можно подробнее?

Comment: @E_K, я не понимаю. Есть ли у меня возможность сохранить существующий дизайн сайта, запустить этот выпадающий список?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы подлючали скрипт bootstrap двух разных версий, из за этого был конфликт

```html
<script data-require="jquery@1.10.0" data-semver="1.10.0" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.0.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div class="navbar navbar-default navigation-mobile col-md-12" role="navigation">

  <div class="navbar-header">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
  </div>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">Действие</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Другое действие</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Что-то еще</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Отдельная ссылка</a></li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li><a href="#">Еще одна отдельная ссылка</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
</div>
```